# Wordpress site design

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm planning to build a site about musicians, where they can register, input their informations about: formation, music style, which music instrument they play, their city, and so on.

People who worked with them, has hired them, etc., if registered, can create a review and rate them, based on some criterias such as, knowledge, price, stage presence, ..., and it will result in a summary rate which will be their final rate.

Visitors can search for musicians using terms like music intrument, music style, city, and the search result will show the rank order, and the visitors can see all the musician informations.

My doubt is, how do I set up my wordpress website? should I make every registered musician an author so they can create a "post" with their information, setting the maximum post per author as 1, or should I make a static site and post their profile information as a page and rank it up?

If someone has some insights, tips, plugin tips, themes tips, etc., it will be pretty handy.

I want to make a site like this: http://www.doctoralia.net/

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: @vel I'm using the underscore framework and will design the website to suit my needs. But I need to know if I make it as a blog or a single static pages.

Comment: you can create a custom theme or use default theme.